# Units in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Which are the units in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$, with $p$ prime?
By trial and intuition, I think that an element $x$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$ if and only if $p$ does not divide $x$. If I'm right, how can I prove it?

Comment: Hint: Bezout's Theorem

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

- If $p$ does not divide $x$ then $\gcd(x,p^k)=1$ hence there exists $u,v$ integers such that $xu+vp^k=1$ and finally $xu\equiv 1\mod p$ hence $x$ is a unit
- If $x$ is a unit then there exist $u$ such that $xu\equiv 1\mod p^k\equiv 1\mod p$ and hence $p$ des not divide $x$

Answer (score 0):

$(x,p^k)=(x,p)=1$ iff there exists $m,n \in Z$ such that $mx+np^k=1$. This means $xn \equiv 1$. Therefore $x$ is invertable iff $(x,p)=1$

Note: $0 \leq x < p^k$.